# Multiple Alert box sounds

Tags: javascript, html, audio, alert, box

I am creating multiple alert box, that all require separate sounds to go with the alert that is being displayed.

Currently, I am struggling to get the other audio to work their alert boxes, rather only the first alert, "Ugh, Thank You!" is the only one working with the audio. The rest of the alerts are working, just without their sound. How do I link alerts to a specific sound?
Thanks!

```
<body onload="delayedAlert();"></body>

<script>
var timeoutID;

function delayedAlert() {
  timeoutID = window.setTimeout(slowAlert, 6500);
}

function slowAlert() {
 var audio= document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];




audio.play(); 
var myvar1;alert('Ugh, Thank You!');



var myvar2;alert('Sorry, I don’t think I’ve had the pleasure of introducing myself.');


var myvar3;alert('My name is Eve_.What’s your name?');



var myvar4;alert('hello?');



var myvar5;alert('Helllllooooooo?');



var myvar5;alert('Can you hear me?');


}
</script>

 <audio>
  <source src="Images/thankyou.wav?.wav?.wav?.wav?.wav" type="audio/wav" preload=true>
 </audio>

 <audio>
  <source src="Images/sorry.wav?.wav?.wav" type="audio/wav" preload=true>
 </audio>

  <audio>
  <source src="Images/mynameiseve.wav?.wav?.wav" type="audio/wav" preload=true>
 </audio>

  <audio>
  <source src="Images/Hello?.wav?.wav?.wav?.wav" type="audio/wav" preload=true>
 </audio>

  <audio>
  <source src="Images/canyouhearme.wav?.wav" type="audio/wav" preload=true>
 </audio>

  <audio>
  <source src="Images/hellllloooo.wav" type="audio/wav" preload=true>
 </audio>

  <audio>
  <source src="Images/wellicanthearyou.wav" type="audio/wav" preload=true>
 </audio>
```

Comment: you are getting value of  first audio only. Try to 
  loop   through all audios document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[i]

Comment: I believe I have tried that, sadly it stops the alerts completely.